# Search around the word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I would like to create a search function that would display the search word in bold and the text is centered (surrounding?) around the word.

Example:
I have this text :

> Purus! Porta parturient risus a hac dapibus nec, hac tortor habitasse
>   adipiscing, nec facilisis aenean, facilisis dignissim ridiculus,
>   integer est cum? Porttitor nisi nec. Platea, tortor egestas sagittis
>   ut nisi phasellus enim parturient adipiscing lorem odio, montes
>   dictumst, mus rhoncus a placerat. Lorem proin, cum mattis aenean nec.
>   Augue et lorem ac augue cursus sit adipiscing! Augue sociis mattis
>   amet! Natoque lorem pid. In est tincidunt, vut, arcu, duis? Cum cras
>   sociis tristique sociis odio. Placerat ut rhoncus dictumst porta magna
>   enim enim sed et tincidunt arcu duis integer elementum, hac dignissim.
>   Montes duis ut. Auctor risus pulvinar cras, platea tincidunt in ut
>   adipiscing, augue. Quis sed vel! Dapibus placerat, ac ridiculus
>   integer urna porttitor magnis platea cursus, mid in.

In this text a search the word **adipiscing!**

And i want for result not all text but just :

> ...ac augue cursus sit **adipiscing!** Augue sociis mattis amet!...

For the moment, i write that

```
 <%= highlight(truncate(sanitize(sound.document.html_safe), :length => 3000), @soundsstring) %>
```

And in my controller :

```
@sounds = Sound.where(:user_id => current_user.id).search(params[:search]).order('created_at DESC').order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).page(params[:page]).per(15)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @sounds }
  @soundsstring = params[:search]
```

And the word search appear in bold. But the research was centered in the word. If you can help me.

I hope I was clear

Thank.

Comment: Could You clarify this please: "And the word search appear in bold. But not centered in the word.". What is not centred? In what word? Maybe provide some examples/screenshots?

Comment: What do you mean with 'not centered in the word'? Can you give an example of the output and the desired output?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "surrounding" not "centered"?  Just trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first occurrence of the query string with `String#index`, then subtract a number of characters:

```
start_index = [0, @original_text.index(@query_string) - 20].max
```

Now only show a part of the original text with the query highlighted:

```
highlight @original_text[start_index, (@query_string.length + 20)], @query_string
```

Comment: I put all in my view ? or start_index = [0, @original_text.find(@query_string) - 20].max in my controller  ? and in the view  highlight @original_text[start_index, (@query_string.length + 20)], @query_string 
right ?

Comment: You can put it all in the view since (in my opinion) this is all output formatting.

Comment: Ok , i try and i have this error : undefined method `find' for #<String:0x007fed656b7998>

Comment: Ow sorry, that should have been `String#index`.